# sp_send_dbmail inserts line-breaks into the attached xml query result

Tags: xml, attachment, line-breaks, sp-send-dbmail

When you use `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` to send a query result as an attachment, you'll have to provide the `@query_result_width` parameter which is an integer between 10 and 32767.
Now, If you use `For XML Path('Row'), Root('Data'), Type` in your most-outer Select query, you may get the send_dbmail to send an xml attachment for you which is really easy to open in Microsoft Excel (just 2 or 3 clicks and it's a nice excel table)
But, if your xml file exceeds the 32767 bytes, the send_dbmail WILL insert a "line-break" at 32767th column of the first line of xml file, and it does this UNCONDITIONALLY! It means it doesn't care what's written there; it just breaks the line and therefore WILL corrupt your xml data...
I've been wandering the internet for more than 5 hours with no positive result on how should I prevent sp_send_dbmail from injecting that nasty line-break.
The only solution I came across was injecting the line-break where I have the control and it's not after 32767th column. A query like the following will do the trick, but it's extra work and not clean...

```
Select Replace(
    Cast(
        (
            Select
                *
            From Table
            For XML Path('Row'), Root('Data'), Type
        )
    As NVarChar(Max))
, N'/>', N'/><!--This is the controlled line-break. Remove this comment-->
')
```

Anybody has any better idea? Am I missing something here?
I use SQL Server 2008 Enterprise (x64)

Comment: This method fails on XML strings of more than 2MB

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and can't find anything either.

Comment: Now that I look back, I'm wondering if this behavior is because of that "NVarChar(Max)"... what happens if you replace it with ntext? I just gave up on this approach and developed my own mail sender windows service... argh!